# django: how to merge a class based view with a function based view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

for some reason i wanted to use the django class based form view "PasswordResetView" in my template that already has a function based view which is the home view, so i thought that i should copy paste the "PasswordResetView" from django's source code in my views.py file and change what is needed but i always face some errors because i'm not familiar with class based views
here is my view in my views.py file:

```
def home(request):
    
    user = request.user
    signin_form = SigninForm()
    signup_form = SignupForm()
   
        if 'signin_form' in request.POST:
            signin_form = SigninForm(request.POST)
            if signin_form.is_valid():
                    email = request.POST['email']
                    password = request.POST['password']
                    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                    if user:
                        login(request, user)
                    elif user is None:
                        messages.error(request, 'ُEmail or password is incorrect')



        if 'signup_form' in request.POST:
            signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
            if signup_form.is_valid():
                signup_form.save()
                full_name = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
                email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
                login(request, account)
                
    


    context = {'signin_form': signin_form,'signup_form': signup_form}

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

here is the "PasswordResetView" from django's source code:

```
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class PasswordContextMixin:
    extra_context = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'title': self.title,
            **(self.extra_context or {})
        })
        return context


class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
    extra_email_context = None
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    from_email = None
    html_email_template_name = None
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_form.html'
    title = _('Password reset')
    token_generator = default_token_generator

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        opts = {
            'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
            'token_generator': self.token_generator,
            'from_email': self.from_email,
            'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
            'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
            'request': self.request,
            'html_email_template_name': self.html_email_template_name,
            'extra_email_context': self.extra_email_context,
        }
        form.save(**opts)
        return super().form_valid(form)


INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN = '_password_reset_token'
```

in my urls.py

```
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class based view with function based view. all you need is to write all routes in `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('password-reset', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view() ,name='password-reset'),
```

Comment: but this way i can use it only on a different template and not in the home page template which is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to access the `PasswordResetView`'s form from your `home view` without changing the page and if so you don't have to have class based view for `PasswordResetView`.

All you need to do is import django built in `auth views`.

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('', views.home, name="home"), # your home page url

# password reset url
path('', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="myapp/home.html"), name="password_reset"),
```

in your template (home.html)

```html
<form action="{% url 'password_reset' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now whenever you click the submit button django will go the `password_reset` url and do the job for you.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work, that form is not showing on the template it's blank , it rendered the button only, (there is no attribute called password_reset in auth_views i had to change it to PasswordResetView i'll edit your answer)

Comment: oh yeah that's my mistake i never noticed that.

Comment: do u have anyother solution i'm stuck!

Comment: Where did u stuck